# size of local strong stable manifold is measurable

Tags: measure-theory, ds.dynamical-systems, smooth-manifolds, ergodic-theory

Let $M$ be compact manifold. suppose $f:M\rightarrow M$ is $C^{2}$.
There is a continuous splitting of the tangent bundle $TM=E^{ss}+E^{s}+E^{u}$ invariant under the derivative $Df$ of the diffeomorphism  $f$ and where strong expansion of the unstable bundle $E^{u}$, strong contraction $E^{ss}$ and weak contraction $E^{s}$.

Suppose the subbundles are then invariant and continuous and have smooth integral manifolds $W^{u}$ and $W^{s}$.

There exists $r(x)$ measurable such that

$W^{ss}(p)=\{q\in B(p,r(x)) : lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}lnd(f^{n}(p),f^{n}(q))<0\}$

**Question** Why is $r(x)$ measurable?

I think we have to write $r(x)$ as set of points like $W^{ss}$ then it is measurable but i do not know we have to whole of points or some points.